# Latin translation of "That it would be a better world."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Context, if it effects anything, would be a shortened version of "Act in such a way that it would be a better world." Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*[ita age] ut sit mundus melior*

There is no firm way of distinguishing between the predicative 'that the world would be better' and the attributive 'that there would be a better world' (though some word orders would tend towards one or the other). Cf. Greek, where the placement of the article would indicate this.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Good point about the lack of distinction between predicate and attributive, but I wonder whether *ut fiat mundus melior* might lean more one way, and *ut sit mundus melior* more the other way.